# Editing Spatialite layer in QGIS gives "Problem deleting features" error

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I started off with an OSM file and used QGIS to convert into a Spatialite database. QGIS is able to load and display the tables just fine but when I try to delete a feature all I get is a "Problem deleting features" error. It seems to be a very generic error that doesn't help track down the problem. Does anybody know anything about this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but a workaround could be:

1. Export the layer as a shapefile (*right-click > "Save As..."*)
2. Try and delete the desired feature now
3. Save and import the layer back into the Spatialite database using the [QspatialLite](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QspatiaLite/) plugin

   (You may need to install this from the toolbar: *Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins*)

Comment: Thanks Joseph that fixed my problem. I am also now able to edit the newly created Spatialte database so there must have been something wrong in the original database that I created.

Comment: @James - Awesome buddy, glad you got it sorted :)